# Generating annotations in Java

Tags: java, annotations, gson

I have a GSON annotation ("SerializedName") which I want to translate from my custom annotation. I mean, if I have "Serial" annotation with "SerialType" element (which tell me what the serialization type I want for the field), after setting the GSON type in the "SerialType" - how can I generate the GSON annotation for the specific field?

Example code:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Serial 
{
    SerialType type();
    String value();
}


public class Example
{
    @Serial(type = SerialType.GSON, value = "test")
    public int field;
}
```

will generated to:

```
public class Example
{
    @SerializedName("test")
    public int field;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at annotation processors. You can find more info [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/mirror/com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessor.html)

[Here](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/) is a good post describing how to use them.

Comment: Im not sure, but this supported in android?

Comment: I am not an android expert, but this feature is a compile-time feature. It simply creates new/changes existent code during the compile time. So, I believe it should work